# Boxing the number of exercise environments

Tags: theorems, exercises

I would like to have an exercise environment that looks like that.

the following code-Latex produces

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,pdftext]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%---exercices style------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{Exercice}{Exercice}%[section]
\newtheoremstyle{defn-break}%
 {\topsep}{\topsep} {\normalfont\itshape}{0pt} {\bfseries}{} {\newline}{} % Switch to the newly-defined theorem style \theoremstyle{defn-break}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
        \begin{Exercice}
            let $n$ be an integer, we pose
            \[A=n^{2}+3n+4\]
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\fbox{\arabic*}}]
                \item Show $A$ is an odd.
                \item Deduce that $A$ is not prime.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{Exercice}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\theExercice}{\fbox{\arabic{Exercice}}}`.

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't work The box goes only with the number, not one with exercise and number and another one for number.

Comment: This wasn'r clear, as your title mentions only numners. Anyway, the `thmtools` package  should provide tools for that. In particuler, see §3 in the documentation, |thmtppms for the completionist`, p.213.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit I find this style quite displeasing, but here's a way you can do it with thmtools:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%---exercices style------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\declaretheoremstyle[
  break,
  headstyle=\fbox{\NAME\,\fbox{\NUMBER}\NOTE}\vspace{2ex},
  headpunct={},
  spaceabove=3ex,
  ]{mybreak}
\declaretheorem[style=mybreak]{Exercice}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercice}
    Let $n$ be an integer, we pose
    \[A=n^{2}+3n+4\]
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\fbox{\arabic*}}]
        \item Show $A$ is an odd.
        \item Deduce that $A$ is not prime.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice}  
\begin{Exercice}
    Let $n$ be an integer, we pose
    \[A=n^{2}+3n+4\]
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\fbox{\arabic*}}]
        \item Show $A$ is an odd.
        \item Deduce that $A$ is not prime.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{Exercice} 
\end{document}
```

[image: exercises]